# Windows 7 won't boot from dual-boot menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows

I have a dual-boot system which was working well with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. But, later, Ubuntu refused to shut down and I had no other option than using the reset button.  Now, when choosing Windows, as the OS, I just get a purple screen.  However, if I choose Ubuntu, the computer boots OK.

Comment: Can you boot into Windows 7 from BIOS menu? If so  try this. Boot into Ubuntu, open Terminal and run  `sudo update-grub`. If you're lucky it might fix the issue, else  may need to look at your grub.cfg file.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04? You do know we are at 18.04 now eh. Maybe an upgrade is the solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 0):

You need a usb drive and download. the boot repair disk. It handles both secured and non secure boot modes.

There are allot of custom ones. so be careful. I would go to sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/

I just had same issue with Windows 10. Worked nicely. Good Luck.